# list of strings - remove commonalities of common strings

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm struggling to come up with a way to solve this problem (and how to come up with a name for this question on stackoverflow).

I need to somehow remove commonalities of strings preserving the remainder.

Given a list such as the following:

```
l = ('first',
     'first.second',
     'first.second.third',
     'a.b.c',
     'x.y.z',
     'x.y')
```

I'm hoping to have a list output as:

```
('first',
 'second',
 'third', 
 'a.b.c',
 'x.y',
 'z' )
```

as you can see, when `first.second` subtracts `first` and remains `second`. `first.second` is subtracted from `first.second.third` we get `third`.  `a.b.c` doesn't have anything to subtract from itself, so it remains.  `x.y` is subtracted from `x.y.z` and `z` remains.

I'm thinking maybe a `sort(key=len)` will be part of the solution, as well as some sort of recursion to end up with the string remainder.  I'm hoping for a clean way to remove commonalities of each string in the list.

Comment: Might want to look at the various "longest common subsequence" questions here.

Comment: Looks like the list is traversed in order, and the operands are only consecutive ones, is that correct?

Comment: it's almost like the "opposite of qualification".... like deduping namespaces almost (i'm not doing that but thats almost what it seems like to me).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams thanks, i'll  study "longest common subsequence" and see if i can come up with anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've thought about this interesting problem some more and came up with a solution.

The problem is fundamentally tree structured, regardless of which tree-like technique you end up using:

- an actual tree datatype (which is how I initially solved it, but it was much more verbose)
- recursion
- simulating recursion using stacks (which is what I ultimately ended doing).

I'll use the following list of expanded list of words since it points out some edge cases that make other solutions fail:

```
li = ['First',
      'FirstSecond',
      'FirstSecondFirst',
      'FirstSecondFirstly',
      'FirstSecondThird',
      'FirstFoo',
      'FirstBarracudaSphyraena',
      'xyz',
      'xy',
      '12345',
      '123',
      '1',
      'FireTruckGarage',
      'FireTruck',
      'Fire']
```

The trick is in noticing that, every time there's a potential lengthening of the prefix, we must save the previous prefix on the prefix stack (called `prefixes` here), which contains all prefixes seen so far that haven't yet been exhausted. After we've done with some of the "deeper" words—in the sense of being nodes deeper down the tree—we may need to backtrack and use an old prefix for some shorter word yet again.

After encountering a word that is not prefixed by the current prefix, we must pop the stack of prefixes until we reach one that *does* prefix the word and continue from there.

```
def ambiguate(words):
    output = {}
    prefixes = ['']
    prefix = prefixes[0]

    for item in sorted(set(words)):
        backtracked = False

        while not item.startswith(prefix):
            prefix = prefixes.pop()
            backtracked = True

        # If we have backtracked, we put back the current prefix onto the
        # prefix stack since we may have to use it later on.
        if backtracked:
            prefixes.append(prefix)

        # Construct new output and a new prefix and append it to the
        # prefix stack
        output[item] = item.replace(prefix, '', 1)
        prefix = item
        prefixes.append(prefix)

    return output
```

Running:

```
print(ambiguate(li))
```

Yields:

```
{'1': '1',                                       
 '123': '23',                                    
 '12345': '45',                                  
 'Fire': 'Fire',                                 
 'FireTruck': 'Truck',                           
 'FireTruckGarage': 'Garage',                    
 'First': 'First',                               
 'FirstBarracudaSphyraena': 'BarracudaSphyraena',
 'FirstFoo': 'Foo',                              
 'FirstSecond': 'FirstSecond',                   
 'FirstSecondFirst': 'First',                    
 'FirstSecondFirstly': 'ly',                     
 'FirstSecondFourth': 'Fourth',                  
 'FirstSecondThird': 'FirstSecondThird',         
 'a': 'a',                                       
 'abc': 'bc',                                    
 'xy': 'xy',                                     
 'xyz': 'z'}
```

Comment: This looks great, thank you so much.  I'm going to do some additional testing then will come back to accept as the answer.

Comment: Great answer (+1). Note that there is a whole class of edge cases which you aren't really considering: try `li = ('apple', 'application.apple')` for instance. Unless you get natural language processing involved or have some artificial way of splitting members (like periods), I don't think you can get this to work for cases like that.

Comment: @brianpck Thanks. If I understood joefromct right, the problem is really about arbitrary strings and prefixes and doesn't have anything to do with actual natural language words nor periods. He mentions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39963368/list-of-strings-remove-commonalities-of-common-strings/39988612?noredirect=1#comment67219044_39963718) that he only used periods for clarity. From his rules, `('apple', 'application.apple')` should simply yield the same collection and the code here does that.

Comment: @dkasak ^ is correct, i'm trying to fit some large names into a small space (mainframe) and trying to keep the names as relevant as possible... it turns out the end of the name is the important bit.  So this works as good as possible for me.

Comment: also, it's worth noting i had to pass in a set to get correct results; If my inbound list had duplicates weird things happen.  i wrapped `list(set(li))` and it works great.

Comment: Yes, duplicates would delete one another leaving an empty string. I updated my answer to use `set` too. I also fixed a bug where the stack was erroneously getting grown in each loop iteration where no backtracking happened so it should be more efficient now.

Comment: Why the downvote, downvoter? I would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: @joefromct No worries. :) It's not a big deal, but I like to ask when there is no comment as an opportunity to learn if something in my answer is really amiss.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to define your problem a little more exactly before writing a solution. Here's what I infer from your test case:

1. "Members" are delimited by periods: the same "member" can't appear in two tuple items.
2. Each member should only appear once.

The problem, though, is that the *precedence* is ambiguous. For example, in the following sequence:

```
lst = ('a.b.c',
       'a.b.d')
```

Where do 'a' and 'b' belong? Your test case implies that a common member should go to the one with the least common members (so "z" doesn't stay with "x.y.z"), but there are plenty of edge cases that need to be considered. You will need to put your requirements in a more exact format.

Adopting the much simpler rule that a "member" should stay in the first place that it appears, the following function does the trick:

```
def remove_common(lst):
    seen = set()
    res = []
    for i in lst:
        members = i.split('.')
        res.append('.'.join(w for w in members if w not in seen))
        seen |= set(members)
    return tuple(res)
```

This gives a result very close to yours:

```
>>> remove_common(l)
('first', 'second', 'third', 'a.b.c', 'x.y.z', '')
```

Comment: Actually, members aren't really delimited by periods, I was using that to try to be clear.  It could be words such as `Fire`, `FireTruck`, and `FireTruckGarage` I would want output such as `Fire`,`Truck`, and `Garage` (`Fire` stays, nothing to subtract.  `FireTruck` has `Fire` subtracted leaving Truck.  `FireTruckGarage` has `FireTruck` subtracted leaving `Garage`.) and yes, I'm going to need one output for each in-bound list element.

Comment: I think the solution to this is going to be fairly complicated if you want it to be efficient and if there is no easy way to tokenize the strings into "segments" (such as with periods). Is there any kind of restriction on the strings that would allow for this kind of tokenization or can they truly be arbitrary?

Answer (score 2):

If the output order is not important, this solution will give you the expected values.

This is by implementation almost the same as @brianpck's answer. But I used sorting to deal with the `"x.y.z"` problem. And some extra explanations.

```
l = ('first',
     'first.second',
     'first.second.third',
     'a.b.c',
     'x.y.z',
     'x.y')

def clarify(lst):

    # Sort the list to deal with the order problem.
    # for ex. "x.y.z" deletes "x.y" if not sorted
    lst = sorted(lst)

    # Words encountered.
    words = set()

    new_list = []

    for elem in lst:

        # Divide elements using dots.
        divided = elem.split(".")

        # New element to be added to the result.
        new_elem = []

        # For each word in a divided element.
        for word in divided:
            # If a word in the element is not encountered before.
            # Add it to new element
            # Add it to words
            if word not in words:
                new_elem.append(word)
                words.add(word)
        # Join new element
        new_list.append(".".join(new_elem))

    return new_list

print clarify(l)

# Gives ['a.b.c', 'first', 'second', 'third', 'x.y', 'z']
# You can make this a tuple in the solution as in the input if you want.
```

Comment: It's really only chance that this works: if you replace the third element in `l` with `"'a.first.second.third"`, the result is `['a.b.c', 'first.second.third.fourth', '', '', '', 'x.y', 'z']` Again, it comes down to the need for clearer requirements.

Comment: @brianpck You are correct. My solution was on the assumption that there were different packs of elements that did not intersect each other. So, we are in need of clearer requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe i was trying too get too fancy with list and dict comprehensions.

I believe i was able to solve the problem with the following:

1. sort in-bound list
2. use a variable for "previous list element"
3. loop, and output the the current element replacing previous element (if it is found)

Here's what i have so far:

```
li = [
     'first',
     'first.second',
     'first.second.third',
     'a',
     'a.b',
     'a.b.c',
     'x.y.z',
     'x.y'] 

li.sort() 

prev_l = ''
output = {} 
for l in li:
    if l.find(prev_l) ==0:
        output[l] = l.replace(prev_l,'')
    else: 
        output[l] = l
    prev_l = l
```

output:

```
{
'a'                   : 'a',
'a.b'                : '.b',
'a.b.c'              : '.c',
'first'              : 'first',
'first.second'       : '.second',
'first.second.third' : '.third',
'x.y'                : 'x.y',
'x.y.z'              : '.z'}
```

Comment: n/m, this doesn't work with input such as `a.b.c` and `a.b.d`.  I want the output to be `.c` and also `.d`.

Comment: You should add more test cases to your question since this is surprising. From all your other test cases, it seems like `a.b.c` would only get "split" by its prefixes (so `a.b` or `a`), but not by `a.b.d` which isn't a prefix.

Comment: `a.b` would split `a.b.d`.  `a.b` is the prefix of both `a.b.c` and `a.b.d`.

Comment: Ah, right. I thought you meant that the pair `['a.b.c', 'a.b.d']` should produce `['c', 'd']`.